# Component Declaration And Communication

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have added a component declaration to the default main.js file which is generated during the Webpack project creation process as

```
import Modal from '@/components/Modal'
Vue.component('modal', Modal)
```

And in the App.vue, I have

```
<modal v-show="showModal"></modal>
<button id="show-modal" v-on:click="showModal = true">Click to have a modal</button>
```

And they work fine. Now, I need to setup a ["props down, events up"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) communication channel between the parent and a child. To do so, I need to add a property, called 'isActive', the Modal component so that the root component can send a message to the child component, that is

```
<modal isActive="showModal"></modal>
<button id="show-modal" v-on:click="showModal = true">Click to have a modal</button>
```

I guess the component declaration should be something like:

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  props: ['isActive'],
  Modal
})
```

It doesn't work, however, due to

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

I have tried different variants without a luck.

My second question is that how a child event changes its parent data. For example, in the child component

```
<button class="modal-close is-large" v-on:click="closeModal"></button>
```

the closeModal event is handled in the following javacript code in the child component.

```
export default {
  method: {
    closeModal: function(event) {
      ...
    }
 }
}
```

How can I set its parent data showModal to false?

Update:

The code segment of Modal:

```
<template>
<div class="signin">
    <div class="modal" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }">
        ...
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close is-large" v-on:click="isActive = false"></button>
        </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'
import Notification from '@/components/Notification'
import { required, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  name: 'signin',
  components: {
    Notification
  },
  data: () => ({
    isActive: true,
    email: '',
    ...
  }),
  ...
}
</script>
```

Bulma is used for styling. And the isActive is defined in the Modal. I think it needs to be changed to achieve "props down".

Comment: How does the code in `components/Modal` look like? Likely you should define the props in there. Could you add the Modal code, at least as a skeleton?

Comment: For your request, I add a code segment for Modal. I am struggling on how to use only one variable for controlling the Modal display.

Comment: thanks. Does the Modal-file only contain the template-tags, or also a script-tag? Is it defined as a [single file component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) in a *.vue-file? I usually work with such single-file-components, and there, the props are directly defined within the component definition.

Comment: Just a thought: Probably you did not define that the imported Modal is the template. So define your component with something like `Vue.component('modal', { props: ['isActive'], template: Modal })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks, your file `/components/Modal` contains a full definition of a component: the template, and the script parts for it. So you can just bind the component to the tag-name you want to use in your markup:

```
import Modal from '@/components/Modal'
Vue.component('modal', Modal)
```

This is basically what you had in the beginning. To pass properties to this component, add the `props`-line directly to your component, that is into `/components/Modal`:

```
...
export default {
  name: 'signin',
  components: {
    Notification
  },
  props: ['isActive'],
  data: () => ({
    ...
```

As for the second question, how to communicate back to the parent, have a look at [Vue's Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). Basically, your Modal component could issue a "close"-event like this:

```
methods: {
  closeModal: function(event) {
    this.$emit('modalClose')
  }
}
```

and when you use the component, you could listen to it like this:

```
<modal v-bind:isActive="showModal" v-on:modalClose="showModal = false"></modal>
```

Note that you should use `v-bind` for providing the value to isActive. If you don't use `v-bind`, the value is just passed once when the component is created. This means, the component would never see a change to this prop when it is changed by the parent. By using `v-bind`, changes by the parent to this attribute are pushed down to the child-component, so the Modal actually sees the updated value and can react to it.

Comment: The modal component does contain a <script> block. I omit it for brevity. I  have tried the code before. With the modal component declaration in the main.js, I get a running error: invalid template option:[object Object].

Comment: Then please show the code for your <script> block. It's very hard to help you if we have to guess how your code looks like. My current guess is that you should just write `Vue.component('modal', Modal')` in your main.js and define the props within the script-block.

Comment: For your request, I add some related code in the script block. If don't define a property, how to pass the data into the component?

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, I get a warming, 'Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "isActive"' I solve this problem by having isActiveDate: this.isActive in the data declaration section and changing the data instead of the property in all methods. Thanks very much again for your help and your time.

Comment: An other way to get rid of the message would probably be similar to the close-event: have an "open-event" that you emit, the parent changes the value of the property, and the child can then react to it.